# Tools to delete and recreate a lot of stored proc in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

We have a database that had a lot of changed in both tables and Stored proc. Dealing with the tables isn't too bad since we only had a handful of changed, but there is something like 85 or more SP that needed to be changed/create. Is there a quick way to take all the SP from one database into another one, assuming the table definitions are the same, which they are in my case

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a product like SQL Compare ([http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/%29).

You can also use SQL Management Studio to script the procedures from one database and run those scripts against the other database.  Right click the database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts.

Comment: I know about generating script from one to another, it's just that I may have over a hundred this time, which is quite a pain.

Comment: Wait, you're right. I forgot about the database Generate scripts (with a s)... You just saved me hours of work and a few punches...